# Excel VBA use of CurrentPage

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code here

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()

 Dim tDay As Date, pf As PivotField
 tDay = Date

 Set pf = Sheets("name of worksheet").PivotTables("pivot table name").PivotFields("insert the name of your filter here")

 pf.ClearAllFilters
 pf.CurrentPage = tDay

 End Sub
```

It can update the filter list every time, but how about I want it to be click 2 items in the filter list?

Comment: Have your tried googlin?

Comment: Google, searching the web there are a lot examples :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your case "tDay" will be first value to filter. You can add more items after coma.

```
Sub SamplePivotUpdate()
Dim PI As PivotItem
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("your pivot name").PivotFields("your field name")
.ClearAllFilters
For Each PI In .PivotItems
Select Case PI
    Case "1 value to filter", "2 value to filter": PI.Visible = True
    Case Else: PI.Visible = False
End Select
Next PI
End With
End Sub
```